# trouble with building the correct LIBTIFF version in ubuntu

Tags: build, installation, makefile, ubuntu-12.04, libtiff

My machine (Ubuntu 12.04) currently has libtiff.so.4.3.4:

```
% locate libtiff.so.4
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4
```

I want to manually build the libtiff4 (same version 4.3.4 if possible) on my machine. However, I could not find this version anywhere. Weirdly when I download and install tiff-4.0.0 or higher version from http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/ it gives me version 5.x (tiff-4.0.0.tar.gz gives me libtiff.so.5.0.5, and tiff-4.0.3.tar.gz gives me libtiff.so.5.2.0).

If I try tiff-3.9.6.tar.gz it gives me libtiff.so.3.9.6, but I want libtiff.so.4 version. Can anyone tell me where to get the libtiff.so.4 library?

Answer (score 1):

The official page for libtiff is http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/, which does link to the URL that you provide. The latest stable version is 4.0.4beta. There is no reference to version 4.3.4 on the official website. Be aware that in some cases the number of a shared library (so.x.x.x) may not match the release version accompanying the source code. As an example I have a build of libtiff version 4.0.2 that produces a library called libtiff.so.5.1.0. The file HOWTO-RELEASE in the source directory provides some information on this, specifically section 5 which states :

> Update library ELF versioning in configure.ac (LIBTIFF_CURRENT,
>      LIBTIFF_REVISION, and LIBTIFF_AGE).  These numbers have nothing to
>      do with the libtiff release version numbers.

Comment: "... in some cases the number of a shared library (so.x.x.x) may not match the release version accompanying the source code...". This is interesting. So how do I know which version of the libtiff behind the 4.3.4 version installed in my machine?

Comment: I can't recall where the so number is set at the moment. As an example of what is posted in the answer I have a build of libtiff version 4.0.2 that produces a library called libtiff.so.5.1.0.